# Render result not the same as my 3d view

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, screw-modifier

The helix shapes are created using a screw modifier. Everything looks good in the 3d view (with render preview on)

[image]

but when I actually hit render.. the helix shape is not rounded, and has a funny hard edge look.[image]

Answer (score 2):

If you're using a subdivision surface modifier for the helix, keep in mind the modifier has different levels for previews and renders as seen here:

[image: image of subdivision surface modifier]

this may explain why your helix has a funny look when you render it

Comment: Thanks, I thought of that and no, I'm not using a subsurface MOD. it's just a circle that has a screw modifier added.

Answer (score 0):

I guess the problem is the Render step of your modifier. Also, you have to check if all of your used modifiers have the same resolution in the preview and render mode.

[image]